# Show that $n \mathbb{P}\{|X_1| \geq \epsilon \sqrt{n}\} \to 0$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems, borel-cantelli-lemmas

> Let $(X_n)_n$ be a sequence of identically distributed random variables with $\mathbb{E}X_1^2 < \infty$. Show that 
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n\mathbb{P}\{|X_1| \geq \epsilon \sqrt{n}\} = 0$$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

Here is the solution my teaching assistant provides:

We know that

$$\int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}\{X_1^2 \geq t\epsilon^2\}dt = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X_1^2}{\epsilon^2}\right]< \infty$$

Hence $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}\{X_1^2 \geq n \epsilon^2\} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}\{|X_1| \geq \sqrt{n} \epsilon\}< \infty$$

and because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}= \infty$, it follows that $n \mathbb{P}\{|X_1| \geq \epsilon \sqrt{n}\} \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$.

**Questions**:

How do we deduce the last step? (I.e. $n \mathbb{P}\{|X_1| \geq \sqrt{n}\epsilon\} \to 0$ from divergence of the harmonic series?)

I do not think this is correct. I think we can fix the argument with the Borel Cantelli lemma though.

Comment: It is true that, if $(x_n)$ is positive and nonincreasing and if the series $\sum x_n$ converges then $nx_n\to0$, hence the solution in the book is formally correct... except that the divergence of the series $\sum \frac1n$ is off-topic hence mentioning it here is squarely misleading. One could also mention that the exercise can be completely solved by a, different, one-line argument. Which book is this taken from?

Comment: @Did What short solution did you have in mind? I'd like to see a one line approach! And I wrote down that it comes from a book, but it was in fact the solution my teaching assistant wrote down.

Comment: Consider $A_n=\{|X|>\epsilon\sqrt n\}$ and $Y_n=X^2\mathbf 1_{A_n}$, then $Y_n\to0$ almost surely and $|Y_n|\leqslant X^2$ with $E(X^2)$ finite hence $E(Y_n)\to0$ by Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem. But $E(Y_n)\geqslant\epsilon^2nP(A_n)$ hence $nP(A_n)\to0$, qed.

Comment: Very elegant indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it seems that what is written is that "if $a_n$, is a sequence of positive numbers such that $\sum_n a_n/n$ is convergent, then $a_n\to 0$. But this may not be true, for example if $a_n=1$ when $n$ has the for $2^k$ for some $k\geqslant 1$ and zero otherwise. However, it is true if there exists positive  constants $c$ and $C$ such that for all $N\geqslant 1$,
$$
ca_{2^{N+1}}\leqslant \min_{2^N\leqslant n\leqslant 2^{N+1}}a_n\mbox{ and } \max_{2^N\leqslant n\leqslant 2^{N+1}}\leqslant Ca_{2^{N}} .
$$